# How to mock Date object in typescript using Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs

I am trying to mock a date object that will be utilized for all the unit test cases. I have many references for javascript, but that is not working in typescript due to type errors. can anyone provide a solution to overcome this issue?

```
// sampleMethod() Test Suite
describe('sample Method', () => {
    it('should match two objects', () => {
        // Preparing
        const sampleRequest: sampleRequestType = {
            key: '0',
            status: 'success',
            creation_time: new Date(),
            attempts: 0,
            last_attempt_time: new Date()
        };
        // Executing
        const result = sampleobject.sampleMethod();
        // Verifying
        expect(result).toEqual(sampleRequest); // assume result also return the same value as sampleRequest
    });
});
```

Comment: can you post your source code ! We can suggest your test code pattern

Comment: @DavidJawHpan, I have updated code, please look into it.

Comment: Will your `sampleMethod` always return that result ! Instead of comparing the whole object you should compare the main data or type . Example like `status` expect(result.status).toEqual('success')

Comment: @DavidJawHpan, my requirement was to check both the object keys and values are exactly same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Jest is developed on top of jasmine, you can use this

```
const mockDate = new Date(1434319925275);
spyOn(window, 'Date').and.callFake(() => {
return mockDate;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@hari   you can refactor your `sampleMethod` and remove the hard dependency on the Date object.

Instead of instantiating directly the Date object `(new Date)` inside of the method , change the method and receive the date object as parameter.

In that way , you can easily mock the Date dependency.

Comment: Hey,  logic here is we could not made any changes to method to pass the test case, please suggest me how to mock date. thats the question asked here

Comment: @hariprasanth,   You could do something like this `global.Date = jest.fn()`

Comment: when i use global.date typescript throws  an error **Type 'Mock<Date, []>' is missing the following properties from type 'DateConstructor': parse, UTC, now**

Comment: mmm.... in that case you have to create a mock identical to the Date object. YOu need to add these properties to your mock

Comment: could you please provide an example.